# How to create a letter icon from words

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, icon

I would like to create an image, which will be a letter and will consist of words I choose. It will be similar to this:

[image]

Is there any tool that makes this automatically? How can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: There are a ton of online tools to create a [**Word Cloud**](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=word+cloud+maker&*). That is really what you are looking for. As for having it in a particular shape.. that would take manual adjustment.

Answer (score 1):

As Scott mentions, plenty of free tools online available. Choose one that allows you to download your own shape if available shapes/ shape modifiers on offer will not do. For testing purposes I downloaded the letter D and created the image below at [WordClouds](http://www.wordclouds.com/).

[image: WordsInaLetter]